# custom style on dialog checkbox

Tags: android

I'm trying to style an AlertDialog to please a customer.  They like the Blue title bar on 
Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog but like the green checkboxes from another theme.
this is what I want to produce:

[image]

So, I've got a style definitions like this:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
            <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/checkbox_green</item>
</style> 

<style name="mycheckbox" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/checkbox_box</item>

</style>
```

and I've got a definition for checkbox_green as follows which are just PNG files:

```
<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked" />

<item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked"/>

</selector>
```

and I create my dialog builder with a specific theme in Java like so:

```
 ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper( mContext, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
 AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder( ctw );
```

But I cannot get the dialog to display green checkboxes instead of the blue in this theme.
I get this:
[image]

I could go ahead and create an entire layout and then use that like this:

```
 AlertDialog shareDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
 LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

 View dialogView = null;
 dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
 shareDialog.setView(dialogView);
```

but that requires styling all of the dialog, not just the checkboxes.It seems so much simpler to just re-style the checkboxes but I'm not able to make that work.

what must I do, other than to create a complete layout and use  to get the green checkboxes rather than the blue?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you CAN change the checkbox inside a multi-choice dialog.

You need a custom adapter for your dialog, so as to have access to the views of the list.
Then, you call method [`setCheckMarkDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html#setCheckMarkDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) of class CheckedTextView.

Here is an example:

[image]

File `default_checkbox.xml` inside `res/drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" /> <!-- checked -->

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" /> <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_default" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

File `DialogUtil.java`

```
package example.dialog;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class DialogUtil {

    private DialogUtil() {
    }

    public static AlertDialog show(Context context) {
        String[] items = {"text 1", "text 2", "text 3"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Test")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            .setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(context, items), null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

        ListView list = dialog.getListView();
        list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
        return dialog;
    }

    private static OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("DialogUtil", "Clicked on " + view);
        }
    };

    private static class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] array) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, array);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (view instanceof CheckedTextView) {
                CheckedTextView checkedView = (CheckedTextView) view;
                checkedView.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.default_checkbox);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** If you simply use `AlertDialog`, then before getting the `ListView`, you call `show`, firstly, like explained above.

However, if you use `DialogFragment` and `onCreateDialog`, then you get the `ListView`, inside `onStart`.

Answer (score 0):

it should go as below...

first design your checkboxes as you want in any compatible format(jpeg,png)...and place them in drawable folder...

then make seperate xml for buttons and select images you designed for selected and unselected checkboxes...and place this file in drawable folder of your project with proper name say here customchk.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/chk2" />   //custom image 
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/chk1" />   //custom image 
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/chk2" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

then make your checkbox:button set to your xml file...as below

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/notifs"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:button="@drawable/customchk"     //your xml
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

i guess it should work you do not need to change the all the dialog...

Comment: yes, I've done that, but need to create an entire layout in which to house the checkboxes, rather simply re-style those that the Dialog would build

Comment: i guess you want something as to change the style of the inbuilt checkboxes rahter than creating new one...m i right

Comment: i guess this would help... some kind person provided me this...hope it works for you too...http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: SO, I guess the official answer, unless someone can come up with one, is that the answer is no, one cannot style just a portion of a dialog such as a checkbox.   The holo-color generator is nice, though :)

Comment: so you do want to change the inbuilt layout...without creating xmls and others...i guess this will be helpful...https://github.com/maydin/gdgankandroidcomps/wiki/Half-Check-Box

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, there's no way to just style parts of the dialog without creating a custom View object.

Create a style like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Inflate view like:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
```

[Here are attributes for checkboxes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#checkBoxPreferenceStyle) to be used with your custom AlertDialog style.

Comment: tried styling the checkMark and others, but still getting the blue as defined in the Theme.