# Change checkbox color in AlertDialog

Tags: android, checkbox

I have created custom style for checkbox

```
 <style name="CheckBoxtpi" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/tpi_btn_check_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

[image]

And apply it to my Theme, it works pretty, but all checkboxes in alert dialogs still standart Holo Blue color.
[image]
How can i change this?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710543/custom-style-on-dialog-checkbox

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives you can do;

1. Change your context from `getApplicationContext()` or any other to explicitly `MyActivity.this`, (whatever your activity name is) when you build your dialog.
   This will probably solve the problem.
2. You may create a custom layout for the dialog box and call it

   ```
           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
   ```